# Can I get a cat?

Tags: fallout-4

I've seen cats hanging around in various parts of the game, but they don't seem to be interact-able. I like Dogmeat but I'm more of a cat person. Can I get a cat for my settlement?

Comment: *This* is the important question that people should be asking. I'm waiting for the mods that lets me find a big cat companion, escaped from a zoo or something. They'd be so much smarter than a *dog* companion.

Comment: You can get a cat to your settlement...but you will have to kill it.....just pretend it is a stuffed animal!

Comment: @Dupree3 That's horrible :(

Comment: @SaintWacko Hey I was just saying that was a solution lol

Comment: @SaintWacko Who wouldn't want a cougar or a panther following them around in-game? Raiders wouldn't stand a chance!

Comment: @SaintWacko: a regular cat would be better than a big cat. Can you imagine the firefights with a housecat that won't quit anD CANnOT BE STOPPED?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of the latest DLC, the Wasteland Workshop DLC, you can build a cat cage in any settlement to capture a cat.

Here's a video tutorial explaining how to use your cat cages.  Then you can have cats freely roaming around your home!

Answer (score 15):

Sorry to kill your dreams, but as of right now you cannot get a cat "companion" type character in fallout 4. However, when the dev kit comes out in early 2016 I am sure that someone will make a cat mod that can be used on PC and Xbox One. (PS4 mods pending).

Comment: I'd settle for a "pet" type of cat. They don't have to go on missions with me, but I'd like them to be reliably found around my house when I come back. For that matter, it would be nice to be able to define "my house" too.

Comment: @Iszi well that's a slightly different question that what was asked. The OP asked for a cat as a replacement for dogmeat, so I assumed they were looking for a companion cat. Now, as far as a "pet" type cat goes, I have no idea.

Comment: @DCShannon No, the op spoke of the cat as a compraison/replacement for dogmeat. "but they don't seem to be interact-able. I like Dogmeat but I'm more of a cat person."

Comment: -1, Seems to me that the sentence "I like Dogmeat but I'm more of a cat person" could be deleted from the question without changing it. The final restatement of the question is for a settlement: "Can I get a cat for my settlement?".

Comment: @DCShannon I completely disagree. Its a very relevant sentence to the context of the question. Its relates dogmeat and the "cat" so that we understand what he wants. If he didn't wish to make this relationship he wouldn't have put that sentence in. Just because you can remove a sentence from a body of text and the text still makes sense, does not at all mean that the sentence was irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

There is a cat that's still walking around after I killed everyone in the Covenant and made it my primary settlement. I consider it my pet cat now.

Comment: +1 for the originality of the workaround, but an answer like this should just be a comment.

Comment: This is a serious answer. I have a cat for my settlement now. That was the question.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but your solutions requires you to a) kill everyone and b) choose this specific location as your primary settlement to work. Not something everyone might be looking for.

Comment: @Vahx and that invalidates my answer how .. ?

Comment: You dont get the cat, the cat is already there. If someone asks "can humans fly like a bird can" and someone answers "yes, step into an airplane and you can fly" is that a correct answer? sort of but not in the context that the person who was asking was looking for.

Comment: @Vahx The question was about getting a cat in a settlement, i got a settlement with a cat in it. The result is the same. No need for silly unrelated metaphors here...

Comment: I agree that this feels like a comment. OP makes reference to wanting a companion like dogmeat, and already addresses the "settlement cat", but points out that they are non interactive. If someone says "I've seen the cats that hang around, but I can't interact with them. Can I get a cat?" and you reply "there's a non interactive cat that hangs around", it seems more likely that you didn't listen to the entire question.

Comment: (Comments in the accepted answer actually addresses the importance of OP mentioning DogMeat)

Answer (score 1):

Wasteland Workshop. Make Cat cages and set them on a switch. Go away for some missions and open the traps when you come back. Not companions. Pets. House Cats. Or DeathClaws patrolling settlements.

Comment: This actually seems t address the answer, but the end of it doesn't make sense. "Not companions. Pets. House Cats. Or DeathClaws patrolling settlements".. Huh?

Comment: @Timelord64 ah the horror of poor punctuation fellow timelord.

Answer (score 1):

Well, like I wrote in my earlier (now oudated) answer, you can get a cat on Xbox One and PC due to the addition of the mod kit. Here is a mod I found: 
https://mods.bethesda.net/#en/workshop/fallout4/mod-detail/1020767